# MYSQL - How to avoid/block insert date with zero value (0000-00-00)

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

Is possible create a constraint on MYSQL to avoid date with zero value or null? (0000-00-00)

May be throwing a error.

[image]

Comment: `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';`  see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Comment: I Got permission erro, is a shared host... SQL Error [1227] [42000]: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation. Can I create some trigger or constraint?

Comment: You can set the `sql_mode` as a session variable too, which does not require SUPER privilege, and won't affect other users on the same database instance. But you'd have to set it again in every session. It's not uncommon to do an initial SQL statement in every session, typically apps use `SET NAMES <charset>` to make sure their session is using the right character set and/or collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';`

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date

Comment: that sets it globally for any new sessions until the server restarts; to persist across restarts, it needs to be set in a configuration file